# Access pictures in iCloud photo albums using Win 10 Explorer

Tags: windows-10, photos, icloud

not sure if this is the right forum - please tell me the correct forum if not.  I have organised my iCloud photos into folders eg

[image]

There is a copy of the iCloud Photos Library on my Windows PC but it contains all the photos in a single folder.
[image]

Is there anyway to clone/copy the iCloud photo albums into Windows 10 folders?  Ultimately these photos will be imported into a 3rd party app (Lightroom Classic).  Many thanks!

Comment: I can't test this as I don't have Windows with iCloud, only Macs, but it doesn't look like it's an option. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205323